# How to get the Sum result with an SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server

I do a Sum() on my query but when I want to use a dataReader it is not working

I've tried this

```
string request = "SELECT sum(price_product) as price FROM product";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(request, loaddatabaseconnexion.connexion_BDD());
SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
cout_total_stock.Text = dataReader["price"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a SqlDataReader, you can just call *ExecuteScalar* from the SqlCommand when your query returns a single value (Sum,Max,Min, etc)

```
decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

However, if you really want to use an SqlDataReader then you should always call the Read method to *'move'* the SqlDataReader internal position to the first record returned by your query

```
SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

// Always check if Read returns false. 
// If false there is no record to Read.
if(dataReader.Read())
   cout_total_stock.Text = dataReader["price"].ToString();
```

Comment: thank you very much it's work with the decimal value !